# java unbound wildcard <?> vs <T>

Tags: java, generics

I am confusing that if the following method are same? Are there any subtle differences?

Your advice are very appreciated.

method 1

```
public static double sumOfList(List<?> list) {}
```

method 2

```
public static <T> double sumOfList(List<T> list) {}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Inside the method you can use `T`  in second case .

You cannot in first case.

Consider this example

```
private static <T> void printList(List<T> list) {
for (T t: list) {
    System.out.println(t);
}
```

}

Comment: Also, in the first case you can pass in a list of any type of objects, in the second you are limited to a List of T instances. Another interesting version would take a `List<? extends T>`

Comment: List of T doesn't mean list of any type of object? Doesn't T mean any type of object?

Comment: @SJuan76 Yes.Thankyou so much.I linked a wrong one.Edited my post with another example,Which clarifies OP's doubt also.

Comment: @user2761885  `Doesn't T mean any type of object`  yes.your understanding is correct.

Comment: But in this case, you don't need to use `T` in the method. You can just use `Object`. `private static void printList(List<?> list) {
for (Object t: list) {
    System.out.println(t);
}` So this example doesn't show anything.

Comment: @JohnB: You can pass in the same things to both methods. A "list of any type of objects" is still a list of "some kind" of object. That kind is `T`.

Comment: @newacct in this case yes, but as a study of wildcards I thought it was a good point to bring up since these two would be different: `<T> void method(T value, List<T> list)` vs `<T> void method(T value, List<? extends T> list)`

Answer (score 2):

In this case, there is no difference. `T` is only used in one place in the parameter, so it does not enforce a relationship between types in two places.

In other cases, e.g. if `T` is in the return type:

```
public <T> List<T> newList();
```

or if `T` is used in multiple places:

```
public <T> T foo(T x);

public <T> void bar(List<T> list, T x);
```

or if `T` is recursively bounded:

```
public <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(T[]);
```

you cannot do it with a wildcard.

Answer (score 0):

In second method you can use like that:

```
T t;
```

However **you can't** in first method.
I think that it's the difference.
I hope it will help you.

Comment: So, why would you need to use `T t;`?

Comment: If you can use T in the second method, but cannot in the first method why would you ever select the first method?  It's a restricted version of the second method.  Why would you want these restrictions?